# How do you cover correctly branch statements?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, conditional-statements, test-coverage

Recently, I've come across a problem multiple times about unit testing in a front-end environment (Vue.JS v2, jest) but I think it's more related to general use cases. This problem concerns the branch coverage of a function.

Let's say you've got the following snippet (I did not add more nested if/else statements for clarity sake).

```
function doSomeNormalStuff(p: Person) {
    const isAdult = p.age > 17;
    
    if (isAdult) {
      walkWithTheDog();
      getWage();
    } else {
       playWithToys();
       driveSmallCar();
    }
}
```

And the following unit test snippet:

```
describe('doSomeNormalStuff', () => {
  describe('isAdult', () => {
    const p: Person = { name: 'Michael', age: 18 };
    beforeEach(() => {
      doSomeNormalStuff(p);
    });

    it('Should call the walkWithTheDog function', () => {
      expect(walkWithTheDog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('Should call the getWage function', () => {
      expect(getWage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('Should not call the playWithToys function', () => {
      expect(playWithToys).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('Should not call the driveSmallCar function', () => {
      expect(driveSmallCar).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('isChild', () => {
    const p: Person = { name: 'John', age: 5 };
    beforeEach(() => {
      doSomeNormalStuff(p);
    });

    it('Should call the playWithToys function', () => {
      expect(playWithToys).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('Should call the driveSmallCar function', () => {
      expect(driveSmallCard).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('Should not call the walkWithTheDog function', () => {
      expect(walkWithTheDog).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('Should not call the getWage function', () => {
      expect(getWage).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }); 
})
```

Do you consider the "not.toHaveBeenCalled()" calls necessary ? Or is it considered as  too much testing (or bad practice) ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It's probably ok. But this totally depends on the meaning of this code. walkWithTheDog call could be called outside `if`, so if it's possible but unwanted for some reason, there needs to be `not` assertion

Comment: Thanks for your answer but don't you think that the unit tests become too brittle ? In my opinion, they are too tight to the current implementation, thus this leads to difficult refactoring instead of focusing on business rules ?

Comment: There's more than one opinion on whether unit implementation needs to be tested, starting with what's considered a unit. But in my book a brittle test is good. It's always more preferable to have failed test when it should pass than to have passed test when it should fail. You can always have more test suites (integration, etc) that test the behaviour. It depends on a lot of factors how much attention different kinds of tests need. If unit tests are too detailed and cause overhead for development, that's not good. If they are too shallow and often result in costly bugs, that's not good either